# Mysql mutual exclusion between rows through a reference field

Tags: php, mysql, select, recursive-query, mutual-exclusion

I will use a figurative example.
There is a conference and i have a list of people that i want to invite. The list is the following table:

```
People (id (PK), name, excludes)
```

Each person can have a person that he doesn't want to meet ("excludes" represents the person id the person doesn't want to).

So, i have for example the following list

```
100, Jack, 101
101, John, NULL
102, Bob, 103
103, Mary, 102
```

It means that Jack (id 100) doesn't want to meet John, John doesn't have any problem, while Bob doesn't want to meet Mary. Mutually, Mary doesn't want to meet Bob.

Now, I want to choose the people to invite for my conference.
The rule is the following:

I select randomly (order by rand()) all the people. The importance of the person is given by his order position.

So, for example, I retrieve the following list, in order:

```
Bob
John
Mary
Jack
```

This means that Bob is invited. I know that Bob doesn't want to meet Mary. Mary isn't going to be invited.
Then, there is John. John hansn't problems with no-one, neither people before him (bob) have problems with him. So, John is invited.
Mary can't be invited, because Bob (more important because he comes first in list) doesn't want to meet her. 
Jack hates John! But John is invited, so Jack can't be invited.

The result would be:

```
Bob
John
```

Other example: I retrieve the following list, in order:

```
Mary
John
Jack
Bob
```

Mary is invited, she doesn't want to see Bob.
John is invited, because Mary doesn't have any problem with him. He can meet everyone.
Jack isn't invited! He can't meet John.
Bob isn't invited, because he can't meet Mary, and Mary can't meet Bob.

The result would be:

```
Mary
John
```

I don't know how to create the query for my need. I don't really know if a query like this would be possible.

Any SQL query guru here?

Thanks!

I rewrote all the question to explain better my problem

Comment: I want to select all the columns ordered randomly, then exclude the ones who are in the "excludes" column of the rows first ordered. For example, if I have (in order) 101 that excludes 102, 102 that excludes 103 and 103 that excludes 104, I look at the first (101), i see that i have to exclude 102, so 102 isn't calculated. In this case, 103 is not excluded, because i ignored 102 through 101 "excludes" field. The return select is 101, 103

Comment: No , i only want to have each time a different list of selection, considering which rows remain excluded because of the "excludes" field of the rows that are ordered first. Each time I call the select with order by rand().

Comment: done! I hope it's clearer now

Comment: It's clearer. But now my head hurts. Can there be multiple exclusions?

Comment: I understand! thanks anyway for your support

Comment: Of course, the exclusions are decided by the position and then accumulated to cut the list. I'm starting to think that maybe one query isn't enough

Comment: But each name has no more than one exclusion

Comment: you're right, each name has only one exclusion, so each invited person gives only one name he doesn't want to meet

Comment: Is the list of finite length?

Comment: the list should have about 50 rows

Comment: @Drew - You might well be right, but I'm not sure that I'd go that far. But I think I'm right in saying that it is procedural and therefore perhaps not best solved in MySQL. It would be interesting to be proven wrong however.

Comment: do you suggest me to execute queries and elaborate data through PHP ? (A query to take data, PHP cycle to cancel excluded rows)

Comment: @Strawberry I was referring to the funny link I provided you, not this op question at all :)